# How to optimize C# code evaluating a condition

Tags: c#, optimization

How to optimize the following C# code?

```
public class SampleClass
    {
        public bool IsGreaterThenZero(int i)
        {
                if (i > 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since binary comparison operators, such as `>`, `<`, and so on, produce a `bool` result, ou can return `i>0` directly, like this:

```
public bool IsGreaterThenZero(int i) {
    return i > 0;
}
```